# 14 day skipper not advancing on Intermatic sprinkler timer

Tags: sprinkler-system

I am trying to troubleshoot my sprinkler timer. There is a 14-day skipper wheel that has silver pins that you pull out on the days you want to water or push down on the days that you do not want to water. However, it seems like the wheel that tracks the days is not advancing.

[image]

I found this [troubleshooting guide](http://waterheatertimer.org/pdf/How-to-Set-and-Troubleshoot-Intermatic-sprinkler-timer.pdf) and in bullet #1, it says:

> The 107T119 silver pin goes at 12 midnight on large yellow dial. This pin advances the 14-day skipper wheel each day. Check for
>   silver pin and check that it advances the skipper wheel. If pin is worn down, or missing, then buy new 107T119 pin.

I have tried to research and find what exactly this pin looks like. Is it these brass pins here? If so, I have plenty of them and that's what I use to set the time. I do not see a silver pin on my dial other than the silver pointer that points to the time.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brass pins have a particular tab positioned to trip the actual switch that controls current to the valves. The silver pin they refer to has a different tab to drive the skipper wheel. They are not interchangeable. If you are missing the silver one, you need to procure another one and install it as directed.

If you cannot procure one, it might be possible to fabricate one based on the brass pattern. The only difference is probably the tab position. You will have to deduce somehow what proper tab position and shape that it would take to drive the skipper wheel. There is likely some protrusion under the skipper wheel that engages this tab, much like how the switch engages the brass tabs, except at a different position relative to the clock wheel.

Comment: Ace Hardware carries an assortment of the pins.. will pick up tonight and see if it works.

Comment: Ace did not carry the silver pin. They carry the $129 unit, which has the midnight pin, but they don't sell it. However, stuffed inside the unit behind the plastic cover was a bag of pins. Low-and-behold, there was the midnight pin. I installed it and it is designed to catch the day spinwheel and turn it to the next day. The brass pin is designed differently so it does not catch the day spinwheel. I don't know why someone would take it out, but now it works.